# Cronjob isn't running

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I have a PHP file to give users 1 energy if their energy is less than their `max_energy` like this:

```
<?php
if ($energy < $max_energy) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET energy=(energy + 1) WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

This is the command line on my server to run the cronjob:

```
/home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html/psychowars/cronjobs/energy.php
```

Well, when I manually go to the link *psychowars.com/psychowars/cronjobs/energy.php* it will give me 1 energy because my energy is less than the `$max_energy`, but the actual cronjob should give the user 1 energy every 2 minutes, but it's not doing anything. Are their any reasons why?

Comment: Where are `$energy` and `$max_energy` defined?

Comment: All variables are defined above the code I pasted

Comment: But energy and max_energy are..
$energy = $stats['energy'];
$max_energy = $stats['max_energy'];

Comment: Error messages? Which account is CRON running under? When you say 'not doing anything' - not working? not running at all?

Comment: their's no error message and not updating the database like it should. Every 2 minutes it should update the users energy and give them 1 energy. But it's not updating their energy

Comment: Example: My energy.. Energy: 3/100  In 2 minutes I should receive 1 energy, but I'm not

Answer (score 2):

A cronjob can only execute executable files. So you have to run the script with the `php` executable. Something like this might work in your crontab:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html/psychowars/cronjobs/energy.php
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to enable error reporting and write the cronjob standard output and standard error output to some text file like this (append this to the crontab line):  `> some_location/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this problem before where my Cronjobs just randomly stop running;

just run the following command:

`/etc/init.d/cron restart`

When I ran this command, my cronjobs started running again

You should be running your cron through 
`/etc/crontab`

and an example line of my cronjobs (to run every minute of every day)

`* * * * *  root /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron.php`
The `*` represent the time

`root` - represents the user

`/usr/bin/php` is the directory which I run my PHP from

`/var/www/cron.php` - is the php file going to be executed in PHP-CLI

Another thing, make sure you have `php5-cli` installed to ensure that PHP can run from PHP command line.

Comment: Well, this is what my server shows to use..
The command lines below will be run on the web server for you at the intervals you select. Please note that the path is absolute so if your script is called test.pl and is located in your public_html/ directory then the full path would be:-

/home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html/test.pl.

Comment: Wait.. Are you using a server? or webhosting?

Comment: @user1893203 then use the above for reference